# Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, arrays, strtotime

hi i am reciving this error: Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string

When i try to do this:

```
$holidays = array("2008-12-25","2008-12-26","2009-01-01");
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$ticketDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->getCreateDate()));
$dayCount = $this->getWorkingDays($ticketDate,$today,$holidays);
$dayToHour = $dayCount * 24;
$horas=$cfg->getGracePeriod();
print_r ($holidays);
```

i get this: `Array ( [0] => 2008-12-25 [1] => 2008-12-26 [2] => 2009-01-01 )`
But when i replace

```
$holidays = array("2008-12-25","2008-12-26","2009-01-01");
```

with this:

```
$holidays = array($cfg->holydays());
```

i get this:

```
Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in file.php on line 262
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2012-08-21 [1] => 2012-08-20 [2] => 2012-08-10 ) )
```

Can you help me plz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're wrapping arrays in arrays. Looks like `$cfg->holydays()` already returns an array, so a simple

```
$holidays = $cfg->holydays()
```

would do the trick